# Are smooth varieties locally isomorphic to the affine space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

A smooth $n$-dimensional manifold is locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am wondering if the analogous statement for smooth algebraic varieties is also true.

> Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional connected smooth variety, and $p \in X$ an arbitrary point. Is there an open subset $U \subseteq X$ such that $p \in U$ and $U \cong \mathbb{A}^n$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by isomorphic?

Comment: @mfl: I mean isomorphic as varieties, i.e. $U$ is considered as subvariety of $X$.

Comment: What *is* true however, is that the completions of the local rings are all isomorphic to $k[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$, which is the same as for $\mathbb A^n$. Thus, smooth varieties are "analytically locally isomorphic to $\mathbb A^n$".

Comment: Just a tiny supplement to the excellent comments of Slade and Fredrik Meyer: if I remember correctly, the start of M. Artin's book _Algebraic Spaces_ has a nice discussion of how introducing _etale open sets_ to refine Zariski open sets recovers, in a purely algebraic setting, the desirable analytic properties of smooth manifolds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely not.  You should think of smoothness as an analytic property, not an algebraic one.  So a smooth variety over $\mathbb{C}$ locally looks like $\mathbb{C}^n$ in the analytic topology, but usually not in the Zariski one.

There are already lots of counterexamples in dimension $1$.  No smooth curve of genus $>0$ can have an open subset isomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$.  This is because smooth, projective curves are isomorphic if and only if they are birational.  In other words, a smooth projective curve is determined, up to isomorphism, by its behavior on any open set.  And every smooth curve is a smooth projective curve with finitely many points missing.

The closest notion to the one you're talking about is [rationality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_variety).  But this is a very, very restricted class of things.  In practice people are more interested in things like unirational varieties, those with dominant maps from rational varieties.

To get an idea of just how difficult the situation is in algebraic geometry, compared with differential geometry, look at the Jacobian conjecture.  Given a polynomial map $\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$ whose Jacobian determinant is nowhere vanishing (i.e. a nonzero constant), must the map be an isomorphism?  This algebraic version of the inverse function theorem is a famously difficult unsolved problem, even after it was reduced to the case where the polynomials have degree $3$.  It is *very*, *very* difficult to import intuition and theorems from the theory of manifolds, particularly when inverse functions are involved (because we don't care when functions exist, we care whether they arise from polynomials).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! But I am a bit confused since I read exactly the opposite statement before. Do you have an idea how the following quote of [Danilov's paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/danilov.pdf) (introduction, section 0.1) is meant? "As a trivial example, a smooth variety is locally isomorphic to affine space $A^n$."

Comment: @Dune As I said, over $\mathbb{C}$ this is literally true in the _Euclidean_ topology.  Over a general field, it's not obvious what the statement should mean, but my best interpretation is that it means that the completed local ring at every point is isomorphic to a power series ring in $n$ variables.  If you look at Chapter IV, where Danilov makes this "local" notion more precise, he indeed defines local models in terms of completed local rings.

Comment: @Dune Basically, the point is that varieties have such a coarse topology that it is frequently necessary to define "local" in a way that diverges from the naive topological definition.  This is why you see the prevalence of Grothendieck topologies, e.g. when someone works with étale maps instead of open sets, they are in some sense trying to refine the topology enough to give more meaning to the word "local".  This maybe all sounds vague and complicated, but that's because it is.  Main point: the Zariski topology is too coarse to express our deeper intuitions about locality.

Comment: @Dune One more thing: in some sense, there is a failure here that is even more basic.  Even $\mathbb{A}^1$ isn't "locally isomorphic" to $\mathbb{A}^1$, because, for example, there is no open subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus \{0\}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$.  So at least, we should think of "locally looks like" as an open set being isomorphic to an open subset of something, not isomorphic to the thing itself.  In $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can ignore this because an open ball is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, but that's too much of a coincidence to hold in other settings.

Comment: @Dune Okay, _one_ more thing.  Sorry, this really is a complicated topic.  But here's a simple example: take the standard nodal cubic $y^2 = x^2 (x-1)$.  It is often said that the node "locally looks like two lines crossing".  This is very much false in a purely algebraic sense, but the meaning is that the completed local ring at the node is isomorphic to $K[[x',y']]/(x'y')$.  This is a way of saying that the analytic behavior at the node is the same as that of the equation $x'y' = 0$.  But the varieties defined by these equations are radically different objects in terms of open sets.

Comment: Wow... Thank you very much again!